# How to Create an Array an Look if a value is in Array

Tags: php, smarty

How do I create an array in smarty from a given string like **22||33||50** and look if the given number is like the numbers above in smarty ?

I have a string say

```
{$test->strings} // contains 33||12||80
```

I want to look if one of the numbers in `{$test->strings}` is equal to `{$test->myday}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be getting your view (smarty template) to perform any data manipulation, in my opinion. I would convert your string to an array before you send it to the template.

```
$str = "33||12||80";
$array = explode("||", $str);  // [33, 12, 80]

if (in_array($test->myday, $array)) {
    // it's in there
}
```

Comment: I know about this but i have to do it, i also know it could be bugy how every thnks

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Smarty but this is how you'd do it in pure PHP:

```
if(in_array($test->myday, explode('||', $test->strings))) {
    // strings contains myday
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do a such things in template. You should do necessary operations in you application logics (PHP) and pass the results to the template.

By the way: Smarty (and all Smarty-like engines) is a piece of... rubbish.